# Facebook Graph Api not returning all posts under story_tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Graph Api is not returning all the posts under a certain *Story* in **Feed**. I am only getting first 5 posts from story containing more than 5 posts in it (e.g ***Mxxxx Sxxxx and 9 others wrote on your timeline.***)

Facebook Graph Api query : `me/feed?fields=story,story_tags`

Response :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "story": "Mxxxx Sxxxx and 9 others wrote on your timeline.",
      "story_tags": [
        {
          "id": "7866205680XXXXX",
          "name": "Mxxxx Sxxxx",
          "type": "user",
          "offset": 0,
          "length": 12
        },
        {
          "id": "18082XXXXX",
          "name": "Vxxxx Axxxx",
          "type": "user",
          "offset": 40,
          "length": 8
        },
        {
          "id": "6155873819XXXXX",
          "name": "Sxxxxx Bxxxxx",
          "type": "user",
          "offset": 17,
          "length": 8
        },
        {
          "id": "936063789XXXXXX",
          "name": "Rxxxx Mxxxx",
          "type": "user",
          "offset": 17,
          "length": 8
        },
        {
          "id": "8535750780XXXXX",
          "name": "Kxxx Cxxxx",
          "type": "user",
          "offset": 17,
          "length": 8
        }
      ],
      "id": "18082XXXXX_10203695403XXXXXX"
    },
```

Comment: `story_tags` is a deprecated field, do you see the same issue with the `message_tags` field?

Comment: no, I don't see in `message_tags`. All my birthday wishes are clubbed into one `story_tag` as above.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you just need to tell graph-API that you want ALL the results. you may need to set the limit of returned results to a bigger number.

try this:

```
GET /v2.5/me/feed?fields=story,story_tags&limit=10000 HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

Comment: @VipulAsri How about now?

Comment: My question is all my birthday wishes are clubbed under one `story_tag`, How to retrieve all the posts under one `story_tag` as it shows only first 5. And the solution which you provided, I already tried that but unfortunately as the query describes it limits the stories from feed not limits posts under one story.